# Get the key value from a multivalue dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following code for creating a dictionary

```
os.chdir("path")
df = pd.read_csv('dictionary.csv', sep =";")

dictionary = {}
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  dictionary[row['trigger']] = [row['void1'], row['void2']]
```

This gives me a dictionary like this

```
 trigger  void1    void2
 walk  walking  walked
```

Now I would like to loop trough a sentence and if the word is in
one of the values columns it should be reduces to its key.

So if I have a sentence like this:

```
"I am walking"
```

I want to have:

```
"I am walk"
```

I therefore wrote the following function (list is now just one row of the dataframe - for simplicity purposes)

```
def reduce_words_to_base_form(test_file, dictionary, list):
 for file in test_file.split(" "):
   if file in list:
    print dictionary.keys()[dictionary.values().index('file')]
```

This does not work however. Any thoughts on what I should change?

Comment: What is the content of dictionary.csv ?

Comment: Are you sure this wouldn't be better solved just by reversing the keys and values in your dictionary? A dictionary is designed for lookup based on the key, and will be faster doing so than finding a particular value (likely O(logn) rather than O(n)).

Comment: @SeanBurton Could you please elaborate a little on how you would do this?

Comment: When you build your dictionary, instead of it being { walk => [walking, walked] } it would be { walking => walk, walked => walk }. The thing you are using to look up would be the key and the value you are looking up from it would be the value, rather than the other way round as you have it at the moment.